# on release action is not working with GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

```yaml
on:
  release:
    types: 
      - deleted
```

I'm using this workflow to publish my most latest release when I delete a release.  I use `git push origin -d<tag-name>` but it does nothing.

Comment: `git push origin -d <tag>` deletes the _tag_, but I don't think that's the same as deleting a _release_ (which is a GitHub concept, the git CLI doesn't cover it).